# How do I get nested JSON data out of SQLite with a multi-level group by?

Tags: json, sqlite, sqlite-json1

```sql
create table store (id integer primary key, name text);

create table opening (store integer references store(id),
  wday text, start integer, end integer);

insert into store (name) values ('foo'), ('bar');

insert into opening (store, wday, start, end)
  values (1, 'mon', 0, 60),
         (1, 'mon', 60, 120),
         (1, 'tue', 180, 240),
         (1, 'tue', 300, 360),
         (2, 'wed', 0, 60),
         (2, 'wed', 60, 120),
         (2, 'thu', 180, 240);
```

I'm trying to get in a single query all the stores and their respective openings by weekday as JSON.

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "foo",
    "openings": {
      "mon": [ [ 0, 60 ], [ 60, 120 ] ],
      "tue": [ [180, 240 ], [ 300, 360 ] ]
    }
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "bar",
    "openings": { 
      "wed": [ [0,60], [60,120] ],
      "thu": [ [180,240] ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the evolution of what I have tried.  I missing a way to do multi-level `json_group_object` I suppose.

```sql
select * from opening;
```

```
store       wday        start       end
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           mon         0           60
1           mon         60          120
1           tue         180         240
1           tue         300         360
2           wed         0           60
2           wed         60          120
2           thu         180         240
```

```
select * from opening group by store;
```

```
store       wday        start       end
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           mon         0           60
2           wed         0           60
```

```sql
select json_group_object(store, wday) from opening group by store;
```

```
json_group_object(store, wday)
-----------------------------------------
{"1":"mon","1":"mon","1":"tue","1":"tue"}
{"2":"wed","2":"wed","2":"thu"}
```

```sql
select store, wday, json_group_array(json_array(start, end))
  from opening group by store, wday;
```

```
store       wday        json_group_array(json_array(start, end))
----------  ----------  ----------------------------------------
1           mon         [[0,60],[60,120]]
1           tue         [[180,240],[300,360]]
2           thu         [[180,240]]
2           wed         [[0,60],[60,120]]
```

```sql
select json_object('id', store,
  'openings', json_group_object(wday, json_group_array(json_array(start, end)))
) from opening group by store, wday;
```

```
Error: near line 17: misuse of aggregate function json_group_array()
```

```sql
select json_object('id', store,
  'openings', json_object(wday, json_group_array(json_array(start, end)))
) from opening group by store, wday;
```

```
{"id":1,"openings":{"mon":[[0,60],[60,120]]}}
{"id":1,"openings":{"tue":[[180,240],[300,360]]}}
{"id":2,"openings":{"thu":[[180,240]]}}
{"id":2,"openings":{"wed":[[0,60],[60,120]]}}
```

How can I group on same id here?

A row will be returned for each unique values corresponding to a `group by`.  Thus, the outermost `select` must have a `group by store`.

```sql
select json_group_object(store, x)
from (
  select
    store,
    json_object(
      'id', store,
      'openings', json_object(wday, json_group_array(json_array(start, end)))
    ) x
  from opening group by store, wday
) group by store;
```

This inner query returns literal JSON however.  It seems silly to decode the inner JSON just to then encode it all in the outer-most query.

```
{"1":"{\"id\":1,\"openings\":{\"mon\":[[0,60],[60,120]]}}","1":"{\"id\":1,\"openings\":{\"tue\":[[180,240],[300,360]]}}"}

{"2":"{\"id\":2,\"openings\":{\"thu\":[[180,240]]}}","2":"{\"id\":2,\"openings\":{\"wed\":[[0,60],[60,120]]}}"}
```

IIRC in Postgres this inner query that returns JSON wouldn't return literal JSON but either way I'm confused how to continue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try using `json(x)` in the outer part of that last select.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. That does work but does this encode each inner query row to JSON then decode in the outer with `json(x)` then re-encode the whole result set as a whole?  Sounds inefficient.  Wonder if explain plan show this. Edit - Yes, but I'm not sure I follow it 100%

Comment: Yep, it does. The tricks with auxiliary data in function calls that it uses to avoid having to do that all the time don't survive across subquery boundaries iirc.

Comment: Alright, that's what I figured. OK, unless there's another obvious way that I'm missing I might opt for generating a different JSON shape.

Answer (score 6):

Adding an example for general reference. [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn)'s point about using `json(x)` in the outer selects is key. Here's an example with multiple levels of nested arrays

The sample data: `select * from tblSmall`

```
region|subregion    |postalcode|locality                       |lat    |lng    |
------|-------------|----------|-------------------------------|-------|-------|

Delhi |Central Delhi|    110001|Connaught Place                |28.6431|77.2197|
Delhi |Central Delhi|    110001|Parliament House               |28.6407|77.2154|
Delhi |Central Delhi|    110003|Pandara Road                   |28.6431|77.2197|
Delhi |Central Delhi|    110004|Rashtrapati Bhawan             |28.6453|77.2128|
Delhi |Central Delhi|    110005|Karol Bagh                     |28.6514|77.1907|
Delhi |Central Delhi|    110005|Anand Parbat                   |28.6431|77.2197|
Delhi |North Delhi  |    110054|Civil Lines (North Delhi)      |28.6804|77.2263|
Delhi |North Delhi  |    110084|Burari                         |28.7557|77.1994|
Delhi |North Delhi  |    110084|Jagatpur                       |28.7414|77.2199|
Delhi |North Delhi  |    110086|Kirari Suleman Nagar           |28.7441|77.0732|
```

For each `region` has multiple `subregion` values, each `subregion` has multiple `postalcode` values, and each `postalcode` has multiple `locality` values.

Here's the sql :

```
select json_object('region', A2.region, 'subregions', json_group_array(json(A2.json_obj2))) from
  (select A1.region, json_object('subregion', 
                                 A1.subregion, 
                                 'postalCodes', 
                                 json_group_array(json(A1.json_obj1)) ) as json_obj2 from
    (select region, subregion, json_object('postalCode', 
                                           postalcode, 
                                           'localities', 
                                           json_group_array(json_object('locality', 
                                                                        locality, 'latitude', 
                                                                        lat, 'longitude', lng) ) ) as json_obj1
    from tblSmall where subregion in ('Central Delhi', 'North Delhi')
    group by region, subregion, postalcode) as A1
  group by A1.region, A1.subregion) as A2
group by A2.region
```

Note the `json(A1.json_obj1)` and `json(A2.json_obj2)` bits to handle the decode/re-encode of json coming out of the inner queries.

Here's the result (kind of long because of pretty-print) - there's a `subregions` array, which contains a `postalcodes` array, which contains a `localities` array:

```
{
  "region": "Delhi",
  "subregions": [
    {
      "subregion": "Central Delhi",
      "postalCodes": [
        {
          "postalCode": 110001,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Connaught Place",
              "latitude": 28.6431,
              "longitude": 77.2197
            },
            {
              "locality": "Parliament House",
              "latitude": 28.6407,
              "longitude": 77.2154
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "postalCode": 110003,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Pandara Road",
              "latitude": 28.6431,
              "longitude": 77.2197
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "postalCode": 110004,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Rashtrapati Bhawan",
              "latitude": 28.6453,
              "longitude": 77.2128
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "postalCode": 110005,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Karol Bagh",
              "latitude": 28.6514,
              "longitude": 77.1907
            },
            {
              "locality": "Anand Parbat",
              "latitude": 28.6431,
              "longitude": 77.2197
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "postalCode": 110060,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Rajender Nagar",
              "latitude": 28.5329,
              "longitude": 77.2004
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "postalCode": 110069,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Union Public Service Commission",
              "latitude": 28.5329,
              "longitude": 77.2004
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "postalCode": 110100,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Foreign Post Delhi IBC",
              "latitude": 28.6563,
              "longitude": 77.1366
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subregion": "North Delhi",
      "postalCodes": [
        {
          "postalCode": 110054,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Timarpur",
              "latitude": 28.7038,
              "longitude": 77.2227
            },
            {
              "locality": "Civil Lines (North Delhi)",
              "latitude": 28.6804,
              "longitude": 77.2263
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "postalCode": 110084,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Burari",
              "latitude": 28.7557,
              "longitude": 77.1994
            },
            {
              "locality": "Jagatpur",
              "latitude": 28.7414,
              "longitude": 77.2199
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "postalCode": 110086,
          "localities": [
            {
              "locality": "Kirari Suleman Nagar",
              "latitude": 28.7441,
              "longitude": 77.0732
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```